# Epidural and cholinesterase deficiency

Tags: medications, obstetrics, disorders, childbirth, epidural

I have pseudocholinesterase deficiency (BCHE gene), but my wife does not.  My wife may need/strongly desire an epidural for our next child. Is this safe for a fetus which may possibly have the same condition as me? If not, then what is a safe alternative?

One specific drug I'm concerned about is bupivacine, which, I read affects me more powerfully than the typical person.

I have read the information from 23 and me about this condition. I have read "Pseudocholinesterase Deficiency: A Comprehensive Review of Genetic, Acquired and Drug Influences". None of the articles I have read with pregnancy being mentioning dealt with this condition except to mention that pregnancy often leads to a acquired deficiency.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Just out of curiosity, how much research have you done about this? For example, there are genetic *and* acquired PCD, and if yours is acquired, can it be passed on? Also, what class of drugs can't you metabolize? What class of drugs is bupivacaine? Sometimes [a bit of research presented](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/411/169) will get you an answer.

Comment: I have read more about my condition on [23andme](http://23andme.com) for which I am heterozygous. 23andme detected the following variants: Gly390Val (F2). The "fluorine resistant 1" (F1) and "fluorine resistant 2" (F2) mutations are so named because they affect another type of blood test that uses fluorine.

Comment: This [reading](http://www.omim.org/entry/177400#33) didn't help because I need to know about heterozygotes, like myself, and that is typical of the reading I have encountered.